# Can anyone help ID this

Tags: identify-this-bike

Recently purchased this but can’t find anything on the possible make on this

[image: Solid yellow BMX frame with custom wheels]

- Brakes are Miranda vision cantilever brakes
- Cranks are stamped European bicycle components (Ventura)
- Tyres are bontrager
- Wheels are grimeca 5 spoke millennium edition.

All parts are original including the tyres previous owner remembers buying it new around 20 years ago but can remember the make –

Also the frame is a steel one, hope some of this info can help with identifying the maker.

Comment: Looks like an absolutely generic 26" or perhaps 24" wheel bike.  The rims have writing on one spoke, and look like aftermarket replacements.  If the wheels were stock, then it seems to be aimed at the "too big for a BMX" age group.

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the fuzzy picture but it looks like the rear dropouts are forged rather than stamped. And maybe the fork dropouts are also forged. If so it was a nicer bike. The seat post clamp is throwing me off - looks very low end. Too few clues to arrive at a conclusion.

Comment: Bridge on the rear stays indicates it came with canti brakes (which it still has) which dates it to at least 20 years old, for what that’s worth. If the brakes or any other components are original, they can be used to pin down the year more precisely.

Comment: Also the double eyelets on the rear dropout and no eyelet at all on the front make me think the fork is not original. Thick downtube suggests frame is aluminum, but I can't see the welds clearly enough in the pic to tell for sure.